# Convert all matrices in a list to data.frames in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, matrix

I have the output of `lme` function in `R`.

```
library(nlme)
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)
str(fm2)
```

As you see, some elements of the output (`fm2`) are matrices e.g. `fm2$varFix`

I am looking for a function to accept an object and convert all submatrices into `data.frames`.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Perhaps `broom::tidy(fm2)`

Comment: The output is the same object (list) but all matrices are converted to to data frames

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
lapply(fm2, function(x) {if(any(class(x)=="matrix")) as.data.frame(x) else x})
```

---

EDIT: Although this answer has already been accepted, I was not happy with the solution, since it does not convert matrices that are in the list recursively, and attributes of elements are lost. I believe the following solution solves both problems:

```
library(nlme)
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1)
str(fm2)

replace_sub_dataframes <- function(x)
{
  if(any(class(x)=="list"))
  {
    x_copy = x
    attrs = setdiff(names(attributes(x)),"names")
    x = lapply(x,replace_sub_dataframes)
    if(length(attrs)>0)
    {
      for(i in 1:length(attrs))
      {
        attr(x,attrs[i]) <- replace_sub_dataframes(attr(x_copy,attrs[i]))
      }
    }
    return(x)
  }
  else
  {
    if(any(class(x)=="matrix")) 
      return(as.data.frame(x)) 
    else 
      return(x)
  }
}

fm3 = lapply(fm2, replace_sub_dataframes)
```

Comment: `class(lapply(fm2, function(x) {if(any(class(x)=="matrix")) as.data.frame(x) else x})$varFix) [1] "data.frame" class(fm2$varFix) "matrix"` Nice solution!